# Column Validation in SharePoint 2010

Tags: validation

I have three columns, "Status", "Request Date" and "Completion Date". I want to do two things:

1. If "Status" is Closed or Withdrawn, I need to add validation to have the user enter a completion date if the completion date field is blank.
2. The Completion date needs to be equal to or greater than the request date.

Any help on this validation formula is appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this in InfoPath? If not, I think that's the only way you'll be able to do this. Don't quote me though, I know nothing about InfoPath :P

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish half of this through the UI, the other half you have to do either through an event reciever or JavaScript.

For the second requirement, no problem. Just use column validation to do this.

For the first requirement you can't change the required/optional status of a column on the fly with the bulit in validation features of 2010. However it is easy to write an event receiver to handle this in the ItemUpdating method and fail the update if the field isn't filled in.

It's possible to do the first requirement with JavaScript but it's hard to stop SharePoint from saving items and finishing it's cycle (possible, but I would look at an event receiver first).